# Обработка не всех запросов к Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rxjava2

я получаю список состава индекса (102 тикера) и хочу узнать о них детальную информацию, но из 102 запросов выполняется всегда не больше 10 и причем рандомно выбирается тикер. Все запросы выполняю через retrofit2 с использованием RxJava3. В чем может быть проблема?
Вот код ViewModel'и:

```
var price: MutableLiveData<CompanyInfoModel> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getCompanyInfoObserver(): MutableLiveData<CompanyInfoModel> {
        return price
    }

    fun makeApiCall(ticker: String) {
        val retrofitInstance = RetrofitYahooFinanceInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitService::class.java)
        retrofitInstance.getCompanyInfo(ticker)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(getCompanyInfoObserverRx())
    }

    private fun getCompanyInfoObserverRx(): Observer<CompanyInfoModel> {
        return object : Observer<CompanyInfoModel> {
            override fun onComplete() {
                // Hide progress bar
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                price.postValue(null)
            }

            override fun onNext(t: CompanyInfoModel?) {
                price.postValue(t)
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {
                // Show progress bar
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот инициализация модели:

```
companyInfoModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CompanyInfoViewModel::class.java)
        companyInfoModel.getCompanyInfoObserver().observe(this, Observer<CompanyInfoModel> { it ->
            if(it != null) {
                retrieveList(Helper.companyInfoToStock(it))
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in fetching data")
            }
        })
```

А вот сам метод запроса:

```
fun getCompanyInfo(ticker: String) {
        companyInfoModel.makeApiCall(ticker)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в лимите запросов к API.